# What is the best way to change the credentials of a Windows service using C#

Tags: .net, configuration, service

I need to change the credentials of an already existing Windows service using C#. I am aware of two different ways of doing this.

1. ChangeServiceConfig, see [ChangeServiceConfig on pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.ChangeServiceConfig)
2. ManagementObject.InvokeMethod using Change as the method name.

Neither seems a very "friendly" way of doing this and I was wondering if I am missing another and better way to do this.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one quick and dirty method using the System.Management classes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;

namespace ServiceTest
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string theServiceName = "My Windows Service";
      string objectPath = string.Format("Win32_Service.Name='{0}'", theServiceName);
      using (ManagementObject mngService = new ManagementObject(new ManagementPath(objectPath)))
      {
        object[] wmiParameters = new object[11];
        wmiParameters[6] = @"domain\username";
        wmiParameters[7] = "password";
        mngService.InvokeMethod("Change", wmiParameters);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ChangeServiceConfig is the way that I've done it in the past. WMI can be a bit flaky and I only ever want to use it when I have no other option, especially when going to a remote computer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method with parameters and a return value using the System.Management classes.

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace ChangeServiceCredentials
{
    public class ServiceUtil
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Changes the user that a service runs under.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceName">Name of the service to alter.</param>
        /// <param name="userName">Username to use as the new identity.</param>
        /// <param name="password">Password of the new identity.</param>
        public static UInt32 SetWindowsServiceCredentials(String serviceName, String userName, String password)
        {
            var servicePath = $"Win32_Service.Name='{serviceName}'";
            using (var service = new ManagementObject(new ManagementPath(servicePath)))
            {
                var wmiParams = new Object[10];

                wmiParams[6] = userName;
                wmiParams[7] = password;
                return (UInt32)service.InvokeMethod("Change", wmiParams);
            }
        }
    }
}
```